# Twilio video rooms + chrome headless

Tags: java, twilio, puppeteer, headless, twilio-video

Probably this question doesn't have much sense but i feel a bit curious if this can be done or it's a very crazy idea only.

I'm thinking a way of sharing data-tracks in a twilio video-room without the need of any of the participants sharing their screen, which sometimes can be a be annoying and can lead to "privacy leaks". An example could be being able to inject a google docs document / presentation from somewhere (let's say from backend) inside the room.

Could this be achieved by running a google-chrome in headless mode and sharing its screen as a data-track in the room? the backend could manage the presentation using puppeter, so the host should be able to manage the presentation from his computer.

I guess there should be easier ways to achieve this but not sure about it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you make any progress here?

Comment: Nope, I had been busy with other parts of the project and didn't give this a try yet, but it's in my roadmap